# Django crispy form __init__

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I've just started to use crispy form and I've noticed some irregularities in how the forms are being described and what effect will it have down the road

From the [example](https://gist.github.com/1838193) in github, layouts are described as below

```
class MessageForm(forms.Form):

    [...]

    # Uni-form
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('text_input', css_class='input-xlarge'),
        Field('textarea', rows="3", css_class='input-xlarge'),
        'radio_buttons',
        Field('checkboxes', style="background: #FAFAFA; padding: 10px;"),
        AppendedText('appended_text', '.00'),
        PrependedText('prepended_text', '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="" id="" name="">', active=True),
        PrependedText('prepended_text_two', '@'),
        'multicolon_select',
        FormActions(
            Submit('save_changes', 'Save changes', css_class="btn-primary"),
            Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'),
        )
    )
```

And the part in their [documentations](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html)

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'first arg is the legend of the fieldset',
                'like_website',
                'favorite_number',
                'favorite_color',
                'favorite_food',
                'notes'
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am confused to see the use of `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` line for the example inside documentation. Why use it when you could simple define your form using the method shown in the first example. Is there going to be any benefit/downsides for any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Doing so in the `__init__` method allow to modify the helper (show/hide button) based on form content until rendering.

Personally to keep flexibility and reduce over computation of helpers, I put it in a property attribute.

This allow me also to have naturally independent helpers for child forms.

Your method is great in simple case where you handle a single form with a static helper. Otherwise, it may be dangerous.

I use a mixin with the given property which allow me to feel more like an extended form api:

```
class MyFormMixin
    @property
    def helper(self):
        helper = FormHelper()

        if hasattr(self, "parent_url"):
            back = layout.Button('back', 'Return button text')
            back.field_classes += ' primaryAction'
            helper.add_input(back)

        reset = layout.Reset('reset', 'undo')
        reset.field_classes += ' primaryAction'
        helper.add_input(reset)

        submit = layout.Submit('submit', 'Valider (here in french)')
        submit.field_classes += ' primaryAction'
        helper.add_input(submit)

        helper.form_method = 'POST'
        if hasattr(self, "action_url"):
            helper.form_action = self.action_url

        if hasattr(self, "form_style"):
            helper.form_style = self.form_style

        if hasattr(self, "form_layout"):
            fs=[]
            for name, fields in self.form_layout.iteritems():
                fs.append(layout.Fieldset(name, *fields))
            helper.add_layout(layout.Layout(*fs))
        else:
            helper.add_layout(layout.Layout(layout.Fieldset("",*self.fields.keys())))
        return helper
```

A `__init__` method which set a self.helper may have done the work too. (but sometime I use forms for simple validation without rendering so, I setted it in a property).

Hope this helps